# /home "cleaned" during ubuntu 12.10 installation on btrfs

Tags: data-recovery, btrfs

I had a seperate btrfs partition for my home directory in my old ubuntu instalation. I "upgraded" the installation by installing a clean system on my ext4 partition which got formatted and mounted as `/`. As `/home` I've just reused the old partition without formatting it (it worked out on another machine the same way before, the only different thing is, that I've picked the same username).

Now I ended up with a clean home directory without any of the old files (I have backups, but maybe not all of the files). If I execute `df` I get:

```
Filesystem     1K-Blocks  Used     Available   Used%  Mountpoint
/dev/sdb6      386623488 169526740 202649500   46%    /home
```

Any Ideas how I can revoke all previous writes back to the installation point or if this is possible? Unfortunately I have no explicit snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever just try

```
ls /home
```

It could be that the installation program made a new directory like /home/bob_1 whereas your old one was /home/bob and it's still sitting there waiting for you

Comment: nope, nothing there. I did the same thing on another machine with Ext3 and there it worked out fine. but unfortunately here it didn't work out. maybe there is a possibility to restore the old file tree